# Unexpected "UNDEFINED OFFSET"

Tags: php

I am using a common navigation file and trying to making the navigation menu dynamically  highlight the currently displayed page.

I have an identifier for each page

```
<?php
$currentPage = 1;
?>
```

In my header.php page i have the following to find the active page.

```
<?php
$active[$currentPage] = " class=current";                
?>
```

and the following for the menu items

```
<li <?php echo $active[1] ?>><a href="index.php">Home</a>
<li <?php echo $active[2] ?>><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
<li <?php echo $active[3] ?>><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
<li <?php echo $active[4] ?>><a href="fleet.php">Our Fleet</a></li>
<li <?php echo $active[5] ?>><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
```

However i get the error  "UNDEFINED OFFSET:" and then the corresponding page numbers for whatever page isn't active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there are no items in your $active array for inactive pages. In your header.php file, replace the code with this:

```
<?php
$active = [1=>'',2=>'',3=>'',4=>'',5=>''];
$active[$currentPage] = " class=current";                
?>
```

You should do it for all menu items, 1,2,3,4,5... and then in second line set the class for current page, it will have the item then and will not give any error